# How to access map value of nested list

Tags: flutter, dart

For example, I have a list of data like this
`List data = [[{"number": 1, "page": 1, "Text": "a"}],[{"number": 2, "page": 2, "Text": "b"}],[{"number": 3, "page": 3, "Text": "c"}],[{"number": 4, "page": 4, "Text": "d"}], [{"number": 5, "page": 5, "Text": "e"}],[{"number": 6, "page": 6, "Text": "f"}],[{"number": 7, "page": 7, "Text": "g"}]];`
and I want to `where((e) => e['page'] == 1)` how can I do something like this, At first i tried `data.map((e) => e).toList().where((e) => e['page'] == 1)` but it doesn't work, then I tried `[for(int i = 0;i < data.map((e) => e).toList().length; i++) data[i].where((e) => e['page'] == 1)].toList()` now it works `[({number: 1, page: 1, Text: a}), (), (), (), (), (), ()]` but not what I'm looking for, I don't want those blank spaces , can anyone help me how to get rid of it ( not `[({number: 1, page: 1, Text: a}), (), (), (), (), (), ()][0]` )

Comment: Use expand function.

Comment: ohh,thank you 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**: Create a new `list` that will be the filtered version of `data`.

```
  List newList = [];
  for(int i = 0;i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0]["page"] == 1) newList.add(data[i][0]);
    // Or if you really want a List of List
    //if (data[i][0]["page"] == 1) newList.add(data[i]);
  }
  
   print (newList);
```

Output is:

```
[[{number: 1, page: 1, Text: a}]]
```

**Other Comment:**
Note that you are using a `List` of `List` in your `data` object where the inner `list` is useless, typically you want to have something like this `[{"number": 1, "page": 1, "Text": "a"}],` not like this`[[{"number": 1, "page": 1, "Text": "a"}],`

Let me know if the output is not exactly what you need and I will adjust the code.

Comment: I know this is useless but this is actually a response from API

Comment: So, was this a good answer to your question??

Comment: yep, but I found expand method, that looks similar to your answer